# Can't seem to load scikit learn on MacOS (pip install)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

If in my script I have `import sklearn`, I get `ImportError: No module named sklearn`.

`pip3 install sklearn` returns

```
Requirement already satisfied: sklearn in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from sklearn)
```

And I can also import it in terminal:

```
Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5926, Jul 16 2017, 20:11:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.__version__
'0.19.1'
```

and of course I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling numpy, scipy and scikit-learn.

What else?

Comment: did you install conda packages?

Comment: I don’t use conda, if that’s what you’re asking. All my other modules have been installed through pip3, with no fail so far.

Comment: how and where(by IDE or terminal) did you run you program get ImportError: No module named sklearn ?

Comment: Found the problem. Funny story: just switched from Atom to VSCode, and the script runner in VSCode apparently ignores `#!/usr/bin/env python3` by default, so I had to change it to use python3 in its settings. Thanks for asking me about IDE. Hadn't crossed my mind.